# Nginx rewrite of sitemap in subfolder leads to 404 error

Tags: nginx, rewrite, wordpress

I want [altnews.in/hindi/sitemap_index.xml](http://altnews.in/hindi/sitemap_index.xml) to load the contents of [altnews.in/hindi/index.php?sitemap=1](http://altnews.in/hindi/index.php?sitemap=1).

I am using the following rewrite rule in nginx, but I get a 404 error.

```
rewrite ^/hindi/sitemap_index\.xml$ /hindi/index.php?sitemap=1 last
rewrite ^/hindi/([^/]+?)-sitemap([0-9]+)?\.xml$ /hindi/index.php?sitemap=$1&sitemap_n=$2 last;
```

Comment: This looks fine. Please show the complete `server` block.

Comment: Your first `rewrite` is missing a terminating `;`